# Java cast cast exception with SortedSet

Tags: java, interface, casting, set

I'm trying to understand why this code won't compile.
I've got a class implementing an interface.  The last method won't compile for some reason.

It will not simply allow me to cast the set as a set, but does allow it to return the single object fine.

Can someone please explain to me why this is? thanks.

```
public class Testing2 {

    public SortedSet<ITesting> iTests = new TreeSet<ITesting>();
    public SortedSet<Testing> tests = new TreeSet<Testing>();

    public ITesting iTest = null;
    public ITesting test = new Testing();

    // Returns the implementing class as expected
    public ITesting getITesting(){
        return this.test;
    }

    // This method will not compile
    // Type mismatch: cannot convert from SortedSet<Testing> to SortedSet<ITesting>
    public SortedSet<ITesting> getITests(){
        return this.tests;
    }

}
```

Comment: Would you edit your question to include the exact compiler message? edit: Also, it looks like Testing implements ITesting?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Testing implements ITesting

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897935/when-do-java-generics-require-extends-t-instead-of-t-and-is-there-any-down

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply, a `SortedSet<Testing>` *is not* a `SortedSet<ITesting>`. For example:

```
SortedSet<Testing> testing = new TreeMap<Testing>();
// Imagine if this compiled...
SortedSet<ITesting> broken = testing;
broken.add(new SomeOtherImplementationOfITesting());
```

Now your `SortedSet<Testing>` would contain an element which *isn't* a `Testing`. That would be bad.

What you *can* do is this:

```
SortedSet<? extends ITesting> working = testing;
```

... because then you can only get values *out* of the set.

So this should work:

```
public SortedSet<? extends ITesting> getITests(){
    return this.tests;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ITesting` is a super type of `Testing`. **Generic types** are not polymorphic.Thus `SortedSet<ITesting>` is not a **super type** of `SortedSet<Testing>`.**Polymorphism** simply doesn't apply for generic types. you probably need to use wildcards with lowerbounds `? extends ITesting` as your return type.

```
public SortedSet<? extends ITesting> getITests(){
    return this.tests;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your declartion:

```
public SortedSet<Testing> tests = new TreeSet<Testing>();
```

Should be ITesting there if you want the method to return an ITesting, or you need the method to return:

```
SortedSet<Testing>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this instead:

```
public SortedSet<Testing> getTests(){
    return this.tests;
}
```

Right now you're trying to return `tests`, which is declared as a `SortedSet<Testing>` and not `SortedSet<ITesting>`.