# Java casting a list of <object> to its interface

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface, casting

I have:

```
class Hammer Implements Part {
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getId() { return id; }
    ...
}

class Wrench implements Part {
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getId() { return id; }
    ...
}

interface Part {
    String getName();
    int getId();
}
```

I am using a prebuilt database manager written for Android SQLite that returns a list of Objects based on what I am retrieving:

```
dataManager().getWrenchDao().getAll(); // returns List<Wrench>
```

I cannot change how this function operates.

Now I am getting both lists like:

```
List<Wrench> wrenches = dataManager().getWrenchDao().getAll();
List<Hammer> hammers = dataManager().getHammerDao().getAll();
```

However, I want to populate spinners with this data (Spinners are the drop down lists in android).

```
loadSpinner(Spinner s, List<Part> data) {
    ...
    data.ElementAt(i).getName();
    data.ElementAt(i).getId();
    ...
}

loadSpinner(wrenchSpinner, wrenches);
```

But it gives me a casting error that you cannot change Wrench to Part. Why doesn't Java let me do this? Wrenches have all methods that Parts do so why cant I cast it into something it implements and use it?

Error:

```
The method loadSpinner(Spinner, List<Part>) in the type NewActivity is not applicable for the arguments (Spinner, List<Wrench>)
```

Comment: I think that WrenchDao should return List<? extends Part>

Comment: Can you paste the actual error?  I think it's complaining that you can't cast `List<Wrench>` to `List<Part>`, not that you can't cast `Wrench` to `Part`...  ?

Comment: What if instead of Part being the interface, you make it the parent class and then have Wrench and Hammer extend Part. You could even make getName() and getId() abstract so that Wrench and Hammer have to implement those methods.

Comment: I wish I could change that but I am using a pre-built jar datamanager plugin. @EdwardThomson updating my question with error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to replace the second parameter of `loadSpinner` to:

```
loadSpinner(Spinner s, List<? extends Part> data)
```

See also: [When do Java generics require <? extends T> instead of <T> and is there any downside of switching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897935/when-do-java-generics-require-extends-t-instead-of-t-and-is-there-any-down)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Also had to add a default constructor. Thanks!