# What is the difference between List<Something> and List<? extends Something>?

Tags: java, generics

Is there a difference between these two `List`s?

```
List<Something> a;
List<? extends Something> b;
```

I know that for example

```
List<Object> a;
List<?> b;
List c;
```

and

```
List<Something> a;
List<? extends SomeInterfaceSomethingImplements> b;
```

are all different, but how about these? And is it different if `Something` was replaced with `Object`?

```
List<Object> a;
List<? extends Object> b;
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897935/when-do-java-generics-require-extends-t-instead-of-t-and-is-there-any-down

Comment: Makind the type of a field `List<Object>` only allows you to assign a `List<Object>` to it. A `List<String>` is not considered a `List<Object>` due to type erasure. A reference declared as `List<? extends Object>` can be assigned a list of elements belonging to an arbitrary subclasss of `Object` (which holds true for all classes in Java). This could mean `List<Object>`, `List<String>`, `List<Whatever>`

Comment: @Tom Right, except that I'm pretty sure it's not because of type erasure. `String` and `Object` are already there, they are just checked, it has nothing to do with erasing types.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. In the other question the asker is comparing `<Date>` and `<? extends Serializable>`. In my case it would be for example `<Date>` and `<? extends Date>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`List<Something>` is a list of objects of type `Something`. 
`List<? extends Something>` is a list of objects of some particular type which extends `Something`.

So, `List<Object>` can have objects of any class that extends `Object`.
But `List<? extends Object>` can only be initialised to or assigned as a List of a objects of a particular class that extends `Object`

When is this useful? Say you want to write a method that takes a `List` of `Objects` and prints each item:

```
void print(List<Object> list) {
    for (Object obj: list) {
        System.out.println(obj)
    }
}
```

Now, let's say you have a `List<Integer>`. You cannot pass it to the above method, because `print` takes `List<Object>`, and `List<Integer>` cannot be assigned to a `List<Object>`. To get around this, we redefine `print` as:

```
void print2(List<? extends Object> list) {
    for (Object obj: list) {
        System.out.println(obj)
    }
}
```

Now, we can pass List of any subclass of Object to `print2`. `print2` will accept `List<Integer>`, `List<String>` etc.

On the flip side, you cannot add anything to the list inside `print2`, because `print2` does not know the concrete subtype of `Object` which is used. Hence you can use `? extends ...` only in methods where you do not have to add anything to the `List`.

Comment: `List<? extends Object>` could also be initialized to `List<Object>`.

Comment: @Ryan, yes it can be. The usefulness of `?` lies in the fact that it can be assigned to `List<Integer>` as well, whereas you cannot assign a `List<Integer>` to a `List<Object>`

Comment: The wording of the 2nd sentence of the 2nd paragraph sounds like it can't be.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, `List<Something>` is a list of objects of type `Something`, whereas `List<? extends Something>` would be initialized to be a list of a different object type, as long as the object type extends `Something`.

`List<Object>` would be a list of objects of type `Object`.

`List<? extends Object>` could initialized to be a list of any data types that extend `Object`.

Here is some code showing what happens when using `Object` compared to `? extends Object`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test {
    class A {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // No error
        ArrayList<Object> arrObj = new ArrayList<Object>();

        // Error
        ArrayList<Object> arrObj2 = new ArrayList<A>();

        // No Error
        ArrayList<? extends Object> arrExt = new ArrayList<Object>();

        // No Error
        ArrayList<? extends Object> arrExt2 = new ArrayList<A>();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`List<Something>` means the implementation should be something like `ArrayList<Something>`. But the other case `List<? extends Something>` means implementation can be anything like `ArrayList<Something>` or `ArrayList<SomethingChild>` where `SomethingChild` extends `Something`.

You can assign

```
List<? extends Something> list = new ArrayList<SomethingChild>();
```

whereas you cannot assign

```
List<Something> list = new ArrayList<SomethingChild>();
```

which will result in compilation error.

You can learn more about Generics and wildcards used in Generics for getting some perspicacity

Answer (score 0):

First one is collection of object type something and the second one is collection of objects that are subtype of something.