# Can I use generics wildcard in List declaration?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, wildcard

Consider the following codes:

```
class Super {}
class Sub extends Super {}
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<? extends Super> list = new ArrayList<Sub>(); //1
        list.add(new Sub()); //2
    }
}
```

Line 1 compiles successfully, but line 2 fails compilation:

```
The method add(capture#2-of ? extends Super) in the type List<capture#2-of ? extends Super> is not applicable for the arguments (Sub)
```

My questions are: 
1) Why does line 1 successfully compile? 
2) Is line 1 a good practice in declaring a List (or other collections)? 
3) Why does line 2 fail compilation, after list was declared to be type Sub in line 1? 
4) Eclipse's autocompletion says only "null" elements are allowed in list now. Why?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Why does line 1 successfully compile?

The first line compiles because `List<Sub>` is subclass of `List<? extends Super>` and that can only be true if List does not allow you to add any new members to it.

`?` means that you don't exactly know that it is a `List<Sub>` or `List<Sub1>`, so it is unsafe to allow adding of new elements into the list and so it does not allow it.

> 2) Is line 1 a good practice in declaring a List (or other
>   collections)?

If you already know that it is going to be `List<Sub>` then I don't find any use, but wildcards are used much when you are passing the List around to other classes like Utilities.

> 3) Why does line 2 fail compilation, after list was declared to be
>   type Sub in line 1?

Because as I already explained it is unsafe to add any element to list when you dont know the exact type.

> 4) Eclipse's autocompletion says only "null" elements are allowed in
>   list now. Why?

Because `null` is of every reference type, this is why you can assign any object a value of `null`.

Always remember [PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super) rule by Josh Bloch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) when working with generics

Good References:

- [Difference between ? extends and ? super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)
- [When do we require `<? extends T>` as compared to `<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897935/when-do-java-generics-require-extends-t-instead-of-t-and-is-there-any-down)

Comment: Ok..so based on my understanding, if generics is used, then only one specific type is allowed in the collection. Therefore, if <?> is used in list declaration, then in order to keep the element type single and safe, the compiler MUST restrict the element type to be null (because it doesn't know what ? is until runtime). Am I right?

Comment: Almost. You can use `List<Super>` to keep elements of more than one subtype of `Super`. But then you wont be able to initialize it as `ArrayList<Sub>`. Then you will have to instantiate it as `List<Super> list = new ArrayList<Super>()`. And `null` are allowed as nulls belong to all reference type.

Comment: Thanks for the references - the PECS rule really helps!

Comment: Yes, it is given by Joshua Bloch in his book Effective Java. Which is an amazing book. Go through it too. Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

Capturing declarations as in line 1 are good in method arguments. See [`Collection.addAll(Collection<? extends E>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29). If you need a list with something extends `Super`, just use `List<Super>`.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared your `list` as, it can be assigned to any sub type of `Super` class. So, assigning a `Sub` type list is OK, Compiler allows to compile. But that doesn't mean, you can add a specific Object type into it.

`<? extends Super>` don't means, you can add any sub type of Super. It means, You can assign any sub type collection to it.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Why does line 1 successfully compile?

You basically define the list to contain elements of any type that extends (or is) `Super`, i.e. the compiler knows that every element in that list should at least have the properties of `Super`.

Since `Sub` is a subclass of `Super` and thus any list containing only `Sub` elements also meets the requirement of all elements being instances of `Super`, `List<? extends Super> list = new ArrayList<Sub>();` is correct.

> 2) Is line 1 a good practice in declaring a List (or other collections)?

As a local variable that depends on personal style, IMHO. When declaring parameters that way (or instance/static variables) that's often not only good style but also needed.

Consider a method that iterates over a collection of numbers and returns a sum.
You could declare the parameter to be `Collection<Number>` but then you couldn't pass a `Collection<Integer>` without a nasty cast. If the parameter is declared as `Collection<? extends Number>` you can pass `Collection<Integer>`.

> 3) Why does line 2 fail compilation, after list was declared to be type Sub in line 1?

The reason is that the compiler doesn't know the exact type of the elements in the list. Is it a list of `Super` or a list of `Sub`?

As an example take `List<? extends Number> list`. You don't know whether you have a `List<Number>`, a `List<Double>` or a `List<Integer>` and thus can't tell whether `list.add( new Integer(1) );` would be ok or not. That's how the compiler sees it.

> 4) Eclipse's autocompletion says only "null" elements are allowed in list now. Why?

I'd have to guess here but adding `null` to a list would be ok since no matter what type the actual list declares, you can always cast `null` to that type.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Why does line 1 successfully compile?

You declare `list` to be "a list of something that derives from `Super`". You assign a list of `Sub` to it. `Sub` is "something that derives from `Super`".

> 2) Is line 1 a good practice in declaring a List (or other collections)?

No. Wildcards are for function parameters. Local variables should be as specific as possible in their generics arguments to avoid problems such as the one you're facing.

> 3) Why does line 2 fail compilation, after list was declared to be type Sub in line 1?

Fallacy. `list` was declared to have elements of "something that derives from `Super`", not `Sub` as you claim. And you can't add a `Sub` to the list because the "something" might be something other than `Sub`; it might be `Sub2`, and adding would be equivalent to this illegal assignment:

```
class Super {}
class Sub extends Super {}
class Sub2 extends Super {}
Sub2 s = new Sub();
```

The key misunderstanding here seems to be that you think the wildcard somehow gets substituted on assignment. It isn't. It remains a wildcard, and only compatibility checks are done.

> 4) Eclipse's autocompletion says only "null" elements are allowed in list now. Why?

`null` is the only value that is of any possible reference type, and is therefore compatible with the list no matter what the wildcard stands for.