# Why there is <? extends T> instead of <T> in java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList API

Tags: java, generics, collections

Why there is `<?e extends T>` instead of `<T>` in unmodifiable APIs of `java.util.Collections`
e.g. consider [unmodifiableLis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) API

```
public static <T> List<T> unmodifiableList(List<? extends T> list)
```

Why not, just

```
public static <T> List<T> unmodifiableList(List<T> list)
```

**Edit**:
This is not duplicate of [When do Java generics require  instead of  and is there any downside of switching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897935/when-do-java-generics-require-extends-t-instead-of-t-and-is-there-any-down). That question intend to find the importance of `<? extends T>` over `<T>` and what would be the impact if change is done from one to other. I understand the difference in both syntax (`<? extends T>` and `<T>`), however in case of unmodifiable collection APIs, context (and hence my question) is different.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question, as I believe that it is (quite subtly) a different question from the [alleged duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897935/when-do-java-generics-require-extends-t-instead-of-t-and-is-there-any-down?). This here deals with tricking unmodifiable lists into being as-if-declaration-site-covariant, while the other one deals with covariant correlation of two generic method arguments. Same language tool, different problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's so you can do things like this:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// . . . populate intList

// now create an unmodifiable version:
List<Number> numList = Collections.unmodifiableList(intList);
```

Note that because generics are not covariant, so you cannot assign from a `List<Integer>` to a `List<Number>`:

```
numList = intList;
```

even though each element would be assignment-compatible. If you changed the signature of `unmodifiableList` as you suggest, it would run into the same problem (since the return type in my example would be forced to be `List<Integer>` once the parameter was bound).

Comment: the version which I suggested would return List<Integer> and so `List<integer> numList = Collections.unmodifiableList(intList)` would be possible, but not `List<Number> = Collections.unmodifiableList(intList)`. Is not this expected ?

Comment: @Kailash - With the current api, it is not expected and you _could_, in fact, do `List<Number> numList = Collections.unmodifiableList(intList)`. This is often a useful thing.

Comment: As no one has any other explanation, I am going to accept your answer.