# How to ensure parametrized type correctness at runtime in Java?

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a simple generic list class. I'm trying to achieve this: given a list instance of which we know only that it contains instances of a specific subclass of a class, and given an instance of this class, add this instance to the list if it is instance of the contained (subclass) type, otherwise throw an exception (eg. ClassCastException). I tried the following:

```
class MyList<T>
{
    private Class<T> genericClass;
    private List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyList(Class<T> genericClass)
    {
        this.genericClass = genericClass;
    }

    public void add(T elem)
    {
        list.add(elem);
    }

    //...

    public Class<T> getGenericParamClass()
    {
        return genericClass;
    }
}

class A{}
class B extends A{}
class C extends A{}

class Program
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        MyList<B> list1 = new MyList<>(B.class);
        MyList<C> list2 = new MyList<>(C.class);

        MyList<? extends A> ls = checkStuff() ? list1 : list2;

        ls.add(ls.getGenericParamClass().cast(lotsOfStuff())); //ERROR ?!!
    }

    static boolean checkStuff()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextBoolean();
    }

    static A lotsOfStuff()
    {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

I thought that given a Class object whose type parameter is the same as the type of a parameter of a method, I would be able to cast something using the former to be able to pass it to the latter. Alas, it seems I cannot: I get a compile-time error!

I could throw generics out the window, go full unchecked and just say:

```
A val = lotsOfStuff();
if (myList.getGenericParamClass().isInstance(val))
    ls.add(val)
else
    throw new SomeException();
```

But, that would probably create more problems than it would solve, and also it would really bug me.

Am I missing something here, or is it simply not possible the way I thought it out?

**Edit**:
I understand fully well why something like this cannot work:

> ```
> List<? extends Number> abc=new ArrayList<Integer>();
> abc.add(new Integer(10));
> ```

But in my mind, the following transitivity holds: the type of the parameter of add() Is-The-Same-As the type parameter of MyList Is-The-Same-As the type parameter of the Class returned by getGenericParamClass() Is-The-Same-As the return type of the cast() method of that Class. I (as a human) *can* know that those unknown types are the same, because I am getting them from the same object.

Is there a fault in my logic, or is this a limitation of Java?

Comment: Won't [`Collections.checkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedList(java.util.List,%20java.lang.Class)) do this out of the box?

Comment: Try with this simple code `List<? extends Number> abc=new ArrayList<Integer>(); abc.add(new Integer(10));` and then read it here [When do Java generics require <? extends T> instead of <T> and is there any downside of switching?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897935/when-do-java-generics-require-extends-t-instead-of-t-and-is-there-any-down)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compilation error is:

> The method add(capture#2-of ? extends A) in the type MyList is not applicable for the arguments (capture#3-of ? extends A)

To understand that message, recall that `? extends A` stands for an *unknown* type that is a subtype of `A`. That compiler can not know that the `? extends A` returned by `lotsOfStuff()` is the same (or a subtype of) the `? extends A` that the `MyList.add` method expects, and in fact, your program does not ensure that this is the case (because `lotsOfStuff()` always returns a `B`, even if it should be added to a list of `C`.)

To express that the two are of the same type, we must use a type parameter. The easiest way to get one is to move the code doing the casting and throwing into class `MyList<T>` (which already has a suitable type parameter), for instance by adding the following method:

```
void addOrThrow(Object o) {
    add(genericClass.cast(o));
}
```