# What is the benefit of defining a class like this?

Tags: java

I have just seen this code and I cannot see what is the benefit of defining a class in this way. Can anyone explain me why/when we use this notation?

At first I thought that an instance of ClassW would allow you to access methods from ClassB and ClassC but I see it doesn't. It is just a notation... but why?

```
class ClassW extends ClassZ {
}

abstract class ClassZ extends ClassA<ClassB, ClassC> {
}

class ClassA<B extends ClassB, C extends ClassC> {
    B b;
    C c;
}

abstract class ClassB {     
    public abstract void isB();     
}

abstract class ClassC {     
    public abstract void isC();     
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

Comment: Hi JB Nizet. Thank you for your reply, it answers what I was asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that B can be ClassB or any subtype of ClassB, and C can be ClassC or any subtype of ClassC.  So you are specifying that is what you allow as the types B and C.

You can find some additonal good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897935/when-do-java-generics-require-extends-t-instead-of-t-and-is-there-any-down)

Comment: I don't think is that simple... for ClassA we have two definitions... ClassA<B extends ClassB, C extends ClassC>. <B extends ClassB> is what you say, that B can be of any class extending ClassB.

Comment: Clarify your question then, are you in fact asking what generics is ?

Comment: I am just asking this case where you define ClassA<B extends ClassB, C extends ClassC>.