# Can I have a list of 2 inherited types of classes in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, parent-child

I have  class Parent and a subclass Child. I want to make an ArrayList where I can store objects of both these classes. 
Is something like that possible?

I tried following:

```
ArrayList<Parent> list= new ArrayList<Parent>();
Parent a;
Parent b;
Child c;
list.add(a);
list.add(b);
list.add(c);
```

To this point the compiler didn't get me any errors, so I suppose it is ok. But when i try to use a method from Child on an object that i got from the ArrayList I am not able to use it!
While

```
list.get(2).countNumbers();
```

This gets me an error, the method countNumbers is in Child.I am very confused, thank you in advance!

Comment: Please specify what the error is.  Just saying that you get an error isn't specific enough to tell what you are seeing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897935/when-do-java-generics-require-extends-t-instead-of-t-and-is-there-any-down. This should help you. Though  in your case type cast it or use `T extends SomeClass`

Comment: well the error was cannot find symbol...i thought it was clear, sorry for the incovinience

Comment: Just an unrelated note: You should use the `List` interface instead of the `ArrayList` implementation: `List<Parent> list = new ArrayList<Parent>();`. This makes your code more extensible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to declare your List:

```
List<Parent> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

This will tell Java that you accept any Class extending or being Parent.

Since the `List` will contain `Parent` types, to use a `Child` object, you have to cast it:

```
Parent o = list.get(x);
if (o instanceof Child) {
    Child child = (Child) o;
    // Do something with child
}
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer. OP, you will still have to cast `list.get(0)` to type `Child` before you can use the `countNumbers()` method. ProtossShuttle's answer below explains why.

Comment: You cannot invoke the `add` method on a type declared as `List<? extends Parent>`. You just need to declare it as `List<Parent>` like the OP already did. Don't make it more complicated (and wrong) than necessary.

Comment: So should i have it like @ErwinBolwidt said  and contiue like Guillaume F. and spork said?

Comment: @John You can't do what Guillaume suggested since it will give you a compile error when you try to do `list.add(a);`. However you'll need to use a cast to `(Child)` like both ProtossShuttle and Guillaume suggested

Comment: Can I write `o=(Child) o;` instead of `return (Child) o;` ? @ErwinBolwidt

Comment: No you can't. Return was an example. `Parent o` is of type Parent, if you want to change the type, you'll have to use another variable : `Child child = (Child) o;`. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 9):

The `ArrayList<Parent>` is a container of `Parent`, so you can put any object that is a `Parent` in it. A `Child` is of cource a `Parent`, so the `ArrayList<Parent>` can receive it.

However, since your `ArrayList<Parent>` only knows that it contains `Parent`, it has no idea whether an object in it is a `Child` or not. So the compiler won't allow you to treat the elements in it as `Child`ren, though it may be a `Child` at runtime. So if you are sure that the `Parent` object is also a `Child`, you can downcast it by `Child child = (Child) object;`. Then you can treat it as a `Child` at compile time. But note that downcast is not type safe, and it may throw runtime exceptions.