# Java, cast HashMap elements to its ancestor

Tags: java

```
public class Depot extends Item2
{
}

public class Station extends Item2
{
}

private final HashMap<Integer, Depot> depots = new HashMap<>();
private final HashMap<Integer, Station> stations = new HashMap<>();
```

both depots and stations stores something which has `Item2` base. Now I want to pass to a function those:

```
Item2 item;
canBeAdded(item, depots);
canBeAdded(item, stations);

private boolean canBeAdded (Item2 item, HashMap<Integer, Item2> items)
{
```

sadly its not good, at `canBeAdded` it says

> "Incompatible types: `HashMap <Integer, Depot>` cannot be converted to `<Integer, Item2>`"

Comment: You can use `Map<Integer, ? extends Item2> items`

Comment: oh, cool, and what is this? Or what is its name? Im not expert in Java

Comment: When using use `<Item2>` in a generic it means it must be that type. If you use `? extends Item2` it means anything which extends that type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use generic wild card here.

E.g:

```
private boolean canBeAdded(Item2 item, HashMap<Integer, ? extends Item2> items) {
```

For more info, Please visit these threads : [Java Generics (Wildcards)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards)  and [When do Java generics require <? extends T> instead of <T> and is there any downside of switching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897935/when-do-java-generics-require-extends-t-instead-of-t-and-is-there-any-down)

Answer (score 1):

Change your signature to this:

```
private static boolean canBeAdded(Item2 item, HashMap<Integer, ? extends Item2> items) {
```

`HashMap<Integer, Depot>` is not a sub class of `HashMap<Integer, Item2>` but you can specify that any sub class is allowed like that ("wildcard"). Making it less specified it you need to use it though of course.