# Java Generics - Class<Interface>

Tags: java, generics

I have created an interface called **Identifier**. And a class which implements Identifier interface is **MasterEntity** bean like below.

```
public class MasterEntity implements Identifier{

}
```

In DAO method, I wrote a method like below method signature.

```
public Identifier getEntity(Class<Identifier> classInstance){

}
```

Now from Service I want to call the method like below.

```
dao.getEntity(MasterEntity.class);
```

But am getting compilation error saying -

```
The method getEntity(Class<Identifiable>) in the type ServiceAccessObject 
is not applicable for the arguments (Class<MasterEntity>)
```

I know if I use like below it will work.

```
public Identifier getEntity(Class classInstance){
```

But by specifying the Class of type **Identifiable**, how it can be done?.

Comment: Try `Class<? extends Identifiable>`.

Comment: I believe type erasure is the reason your first attempt is failing.  But can you explain to us why you think you need to pass class type information into your method?

Comment: u are right. Its working. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change DAO method signature to

```
public Identifier getEntity(Class<? extends Identifier> classInstance)
```

By declaring method as you described above you specify that the only applicable argument is `Identifier.class` itself. To be able to accept `Identifier.class` implementations, you should define [generic type bounds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

> `List<? extends Shape>` is an example of a bounded wildcard. The `?` stands for an unknown type, just like the wildcards we saw earlier. However, in this case, we know that this unknown type is in fact a subtype of Shape. (Note: It could be Shape itself, or some subclass; it need not literally extend Shape.) We say that Shape is the upper bound of the wildcard.

Also you can take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/897973/1782379