# How to let the return value remain generic (without casting) when a method of a class with a bounded type parameter returns a value of its own type?

Tags: java, generics

I have a class `A` which contains a field of type `A` (similar to the way a `Node` in an implementation of a linked list has a `Node nextNode`) like so:

```
public class A {

    private A otherA;

    public A getOtherA() {
        return otherA;
    }
}
```

Then I have a class `B` with a bounded type parameter of `<T extends A>` which attempts to assign the return value from `getOtherA()` to a variable of type `T`:

```
public class B<T extends A> {

    public B(T t1) {
        T t2 = t1.getOtherA();
    }
}
```

---

The above code produces an error at the line

```
T t2 = t1.getOtherA();
```

and reads as

```
Incompatible types.  Required T, Found A.
```

My question is **how (if possible) do I modify the code so that I can treat the return value of `getOtherA()` as type `T`**.  After all, `t1` is of type `T`, `T` extends `A` and `getOtherA()` just returns an object of the same type as the object it belongs to. So why does `T#getOtherA()` not have a return type of `T`?

It seems to me that my compiler should be satisfied that `t1.getOtherA()` always returns an object of type `T`, but I suspect that I have a misunderstanding of generics, in which case I'll bite the bullet and just cast each one to my desired type.

Comment: Possibly because `getOtherA` returns and object of type `A` and not `T`? `T` can be `A` but there is no guarentee that and `A` is a `T`?.. // Maybe this answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/897973/2985796 ) can provide a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because `getOtherA()` returns an `A`, which is not necessarily a `T`.

You can get close to you requirements if you make `A` generic, with the type parameter intended to be the class `A` itself.

```
// Introduce type parameter T, upper bound itself.
class A<T extends A<T>> {
    protected T otherA;  // now of type T

    public T getOtherA() {  // now returns T
        return otherA;
    }
}
```

Any subclasses of `A` are expected to supply themselves as a type parameter:

```
class ASub extends A<ASub> {
    // Implementation
}
```

Or they can declare their own type parameter with a similar constraint:

```
class ASub<T extends ASub<T>> extends A<T> {
    // Implementation
}
```

This means that `getOtherA` can be typed to return an object of its own type.

Class `B` will supply its `T` to `A`.

```
class B<T extends A<T>> {
    public B(T t1) {
        T t2 = t1.getOtherA();
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use this solution because it would require me to edit the interface of A, but it fully answers my question so I'll accept. Thanks.

Comment: The bound on `T` in the declaration of `A` is unnecessary. `class A<T>` is sufficient