# How to manage a collection for a type which extends another?

Tags: java, collections, extends

I have the following situation:

```
public class A {...};
public class B extends A {...};
```

And I defined a function inside a `class C` with the following header:

```
private void handleABC(final Collection<A>) {...}
```

but I get the following message when I try to call it passing type `B`:

> The method handleABC(Collection) in the type C is not applicable for the arguments (Collection).

Should't this work for both `A` and `B` since I defined the method `Collection<A>` and `B` extends from `A`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use `Collection<? extends A>` in your `handleABC` declaration.

Comment: @Berger `C c = new C();
        c.handleABC(Arrays.asList(new B()));` works fine for me because `B` is a type of `A`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`B extends A`, yes, but `Collection<B> extends Collection<A>` is not the case.

As someone mentioned in a comment, try `Collection<? extends A>`.

Answer (score 2):

change the `handleABC()` signature to

```
private void handleABC (final Collection<? extends A> )
```

so that the methods accepts Collection of subclasses of A.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the class specified in diamond operator, not concrete classes or you can use "? extends A". You can read this link : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

Please review this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/897973/3465242

```
<T extends SomeClass>
```

when the actual parameter can be SomeClass or any subtype of it.

In your case

```
private void handleABC (final Collection<? extends A> )
```