# <R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper) Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I was looking at the stream interface and found this method :

```
 <R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
```

I can't find any reason why "? extends R" instead of R :

```
 <R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, R> mapper);
```

so what will be the difference if I make it like above ?  isn't the "?" is the R variable that I pass ? and it will extend R I can't find a reason for it.

Comment: This is too support the polymorphism and dynamic binding.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It uses `? extends R` to allow functions taken by `map` to be declared as returning a subtype of `R`

For example, given this stream:

```
Stream<Number> numberStream = Stream.of(1, 2L);
```

In the following `map` call, `R` is `Number`, but the function is of type `Function<Number, Integer>`:

```
Function<Number, Integer> function = n -> Integer.valueOf(n.intValue());
Stream<Number> numberStream2 = numberStream.map(function); //would have failed
```

If it did not take `? extends R`, then `function` would have been an invalid argument (`Function<Number, Number>` would have been required)

Comment: @earnest_k `R` here is anything that the integer extends right ? it's not only number. just to be a generic answer as "? extends R". Thanks for the answer

Comment: @MohammadKarmi There are two `R` in this answer. For `Function<Number, Integer>`, `R` is `Integer`. For `numberStream.map(function)`, `R` is `Number`.

Comment: correct. but I can use anything that the integer extend :
`Stream<Serliazable> numberStream2 = numberStream.map(function);`
so R can be anything the integer extend here. that's what I wanted to say. in your example it's number Thanks :)

Comment: No. It has to be `Number` or a subtype of `Number`. So you can't use, for example, `Function<Number, Object>` (`Integer` extends `Object`, but that would be invalid because `Object` is not a subtype of `Number`). If you mean *anything that extends `Integer`*, then yes - but `Integer` is a bad example because there's no subtype we could use to illustrate it :-)

Comment: No what I meant is that , R is the super of the Integer here. that's why this work :
`Stream<Serliazable> numberStream2 = numberStream.map(function);` R here is serliazable , please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: That's correct. `R` is `Serializable` in that case, just as `R` was `Number` in my example.

Comment: Why is <? super T> in such a place?

Answer (score 2):

`? extends R` means you can pass an object whose class is derived by `R`, a.k.a subclass of `R`.

So the map function can produce `R` and `R's subclass` as result. That is reasonable.

For example, If we have these classes:
`Animal`, `Groose (extends Animal)`, `Egg`
`Function<Egg, Groose> hatching`

You can write this code:

```
List<Egg> eggs = getEggs();
List<Animal> myPets = eggs.stream().map(hatching)....
```

You can see that your `map` function requires `Animal` type (`R`), but your mapper returns `Groose` type (which is `? extends R`). If the `map` function writes as `<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, R> mapper);`, you have to add another conversion from `Groose` to `Animal`.

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897935/when-do-java-generics-require-extends-t-instead-of-t-and-is-there-any-down) and understand `<? extends T>`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java Generics are invariant which means that even if S extends P the following code will throw the compile error -

```
List<S> list1 = neww ArrayList<>();
List<P> list2 = list1 ; // compile error
```

But if you have Listthen you can do the following:

```
List<S> list1 = neww ArrayList<>();
List<? extends P> list2 = list1 ;
```