# Use methods inside a generic type

Tags: java, generics, generic-function

Consider this class:

```
public class A {
   public void method_a(){
       System.out.println("THIS IS IT");
 }
}
```

I want to use 'method_a' in another function using generic type to get class A.
for example:

```
public class B {
    public void calling_this(){
        A = new A();
        method_b(A);
    }
    public <T> void method_b(T m){
        m.method_a();
    }
}
```

I get error "cannot find symbol" on `m.method_a()`. 
Is this method possible or is there any thing like equivalent to it?

Comment: If you will always pass an instance of type `A` to `method_b` why does it have to be generic? It can just be `method_b(A m)`

Comment: You are confused as to what a generic type is; also, your naming conventions of `class A` and `Class A` are quite confusing. Please expand on how you intend to use this. You want to call `B.calling_this()` and have it invoke `method_a()` on some non-existent instance of `A`? Why?

Comment: @nabster Worst suggestion ever. Why even bother with generics, if you're just going to bypass type safety and cast everything? You might as well just define parameter as `Object`.

Comment: Actually I made my code simple showing only the way I'm doing it. I'm using JPA repository to get data and do similar tasks so I just want to use one function but using different repository instance. @user7

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I described in my last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With generics you can set some restrictions

```
interface HasMethodA {
    void method_a();
}

...

class ... {

    <T extends HasMethodA> ... (..., T hasMethodA, ...) {
        ...
        hasMethodA.method_a();
        ...
    }

}
```

See [Bounded Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)

Answer (score 3):

Define your method as

```
    public <T extends A> void method_b(T m){
        m.method_a();
    }
```

[When do Java generics require <? extends T> instead of <T> and is there any downside of switching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897935/when-do-java-generics-require-extends-t-instead-of-t-and-is-there-any-down)