# incompatible types: Myclass cannot be converted to CAP#1 where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:CAP#1 extends Myclass from capture of ? extends Myclass

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, extends

In code I created user defined class Myclass and Myclass2 which extends Myclass and then used in ArrayList<? extends Myclass> as a arguments that means now we can pass ArrayList of Myclass and the class which extends Myclass  but it is not working it comes up with incompatible types: Myclass cannot be converted to CAP#1 where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:CAP#1 extends Myclass from capture of ? extends Myclass

so How we can make such argument that holds object which extends Myclass?

```
class Myclass{

}

class Myclass2 extends Myclass{

}





public class GenericCheck{

public static void method (ArrayList<? extends Myclass> al){
al.add(new Myclass());

}

public static void main(String args[]){

   ArrayList<Myclass> al = new ArrayList();

   GenericCheck.method(al);

}

}
```

Comment: "so How we can make such argument that holds object which extends Myclass?" You can't. Why do you think you can?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do Java generics require <? extends T> instead of <T> and is there any downside of switching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897935/when-do-java-generics-require-extends-t-instead-of-t-and-is-there-any-down)

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with the line `GenericCheck.method(al);`. You can pass an `ArrayList<Myclass>` to a parameter of type `ArrayList<? extends Myclass>`. There is no problem there.

The problem is with the line `al.add(new Myclass());` inside the `method()` method. `a1` is an `ArrayList<? extends Myclass>`, which is an ArrayList of *unknown type argument*. You cannot assume anything about the type argument, except that it is `Myclass` or a subtype of `Myclass`. If it is a subclass of `Myclass`, then adding `new Myclass()` (a `Myclass` instance) to it is not allowed. Basically, you cannot guarantee that `Myclass` is assignable to the *unknown type*, so you cannot pass it.

More generally, you can think of it through the PECS (Producer `extends`, Consumer `super`) idiom. If you use an `extends` wildcard, the ArrayList can only be used as a "producer" inside the `method()` method -- you can only get things out of it, and you can never add anything to it (except `null`). If the parameter had a `super` wildcard instead (e.g. `public static void method (ArrayList<? super Myclass> al)`), you *would* be able to add `Myclass` to it, though you would only be able to get things out as `Object`. It is rarely useful to use `super` wildcards on ArrayList. You probably want no wildcard instead, i.e. `public static void method (ArrayList<Myclass> al)`.